# std::this_thread::sleep_for MS implementation on 32 bit time_t

Tags: c++, c++11, std

We are using a 32 bit time_t type and the std threading. I'm trying to sleep a thread using this code:

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
```

I'm getting a warning that I'm trying to `convert __64bit` to time_t (which is 32), loss of precision. When looking further the error is caused by this line in the "chrono" file of Microsoft:

```
(750) _Xt.sec = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(_T0).count();
```

`_Xt.sec is of type time_t,  chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(_T0).count() is of type __64 bit`. Seems like Ms implementation of `std::chrono` cannot handle 32 bit time_t?

You can find an example project of the problem here: 
http://jimber.org/stdthread32bittimet.zip

Comment: Tested on VS2013, no problem. Which version of compiler are you using?

Comment: Looking at the *crtdefs.h* VC header, it seems `time_t` is 32-bit only if you `#define _USE_32BIT_TIME_T`. Are you doing that, and is that something you can get rid of? If not, your best bet is to probably use [`#pragma`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx) directives around that line to disable/re-enable that warning. Incidentally, if you want to sleep the thread for `std::chrono::minutes(1)` or `std::chrono::hours(1)` that would eliminate the warning too :)

Comment: I'm using v110_xp of the compiler (vs2012). I can't get rid of _USE_32BIT_TIME_T, it's defined in the preprocessor definitions and it breaks other things. Disabling and re enabling the warning seems a doable option...

Comment: Be aware that by doing that you may be truncating the `count()` result. [`std::chrono::seconds`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) requires a signed type of at 35 bit width for its representation.

Comment: @Praetorian: So std::chrono::seconds should not be used with 32bit time_t? Or what is the exact issue here?

Comment: @JDel The problem boils down to an incompatibility between the `_USE_32BIT_TIME_T` setting and `std::chrono::seconds`, which requires at least 35 bits for its representation. The VC implementation internally converts your relative time to `time_since_epoch()`and then attempts to assign the `count()`, which returns a 64-bit result due to earlier requirement, for this duration to `time_t`, which is 32-bit in your case. Hence the warning.